# Can stdcall have a variable arguments?

Tags: windows, winapi, calling-convention, stdcall, variadic-functions

As far as I know, only the caller-clean-stack convention can use variable arguments.
By the way, the WinApi StringCchPrintfW is declared like this.(I removed the SAL)

> __inline HRESULT **__stdcall**
>   StringCchPrintfW(
>   STRSAFE_LPWSTR pszDest, size_t cchDest, STRSAFE_LPCWSTR pszFormat, **...**
>   );

Can stdcall have a variable arguments either?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The [stdcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93(v=VS.71).aspx) calling convention has the callee clean the stack.  Since the callee is cleaning the stack there is no way for it to know at compile time how much to pop off, therefore it cannot have variable arguments.

In order to have variable number of function arguments you need to use [cdecl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks(VS.71).aspx), which has the caller clean the stack.  This all the compiler to determine how many arguments are being passed and since the caller is cleaning up the stack it also knows how much to pop off the stack when the call to the function returns.

In the case mentioned above, the function is declared to use `__stdcall`, which as previously mentioned does not support variable arguments.  In this case, the compiler makes the decision to ignore the calling convention defined and revert back to `__cdecl`.  This behavior is alluded to in the description for [stdcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93(v=VS.71).aspx), mentioned above.  I quote:

> The callee cleans the stack, so the
>   compiler makes **vararg** functions
>   **__cdecl**.

This can be observed if the following code is compiled and a call to the function disassembled.

```
int __stdcall Bar(int a, int b, ...)
{
  return b * a;
}
```

The resulting code will be treated as `__cdecl`.  As to the **reason** this is defined that way, I do not know.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that.  Got confused with the old `pascal` calling convention.

Comment: I don't think the point is left-to-right or right-to-left order, by the way.
The point is who has a responsiblity to clean-up the stack.

Comment: Exactly. I just updated my answer.  Before `stdcall`, there was the `pascal` calling convention, you can find that in the link you referenced.  That had the left to right argument pushing.

Comment: It(inline) makes a sense. But why they did write the stdcall explicitly. It gives me a confusion.

Comment: Your answer has been modified to a nice one! Thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin: Right to left vs. left to right also plays a part. With R2L, the first argument is at the top of the stack so you can use that to figure out how many more arguments are on the stack. With L2R, the *last* argument is on the stop of the stack. Since that's a variable argument of some unknown type, it's not much use in figuring out what else was passed.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: What does some unknown type mean? Give me more hints. Thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin: Consider printf as an example. The first argument tells the types of the rest of the arguments. With arguments pushed R2L, that's at the top of the stack so `printf` can use it to determine the types of the others. If the arguments pushed L2R, the TOS would be the *last* argument pushed, which could be an int or a long or a double, or whatever, but doesn't tell `printf` anything about the other arguments.